# How to replace all spaces by underscores and remove all the parentheses without using replace() function?

Tags: python, replace, removeall

Here is what I did. I know this is definitely wrong. I'd like to know how to make this one work? Thx!

```
import re
def demicrosoft (fn):

"""Clean up a file name.

Remove all parentheses and replace all spaces by underscores.

Params: fn (string): 
Returns: (string) clean version of fn
"""

fn = re.sub('[()]', '', fn)
for ch in ['']:
    fn = fn.translate(ch, "_")
return fn

print(demicrosoft('Quercus stellata (26).jpg'))
```

Comment: What exactly is not working the way you expect?

Comment: It says there is a TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: That should be added to your question since that is really the thing you are asking about. Also, explain what is confusing you about "it takes 1 argument but you gave 2".

Comment: what a silly requirement ... if this is for a class GL on the test ... if this is for a job GL in the interview ... in either case the correct answer is `"why the hell would i choose not to use .replace"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) combined with a generator that iterates over the characters in your string while handling the logic for filtering out parentheses and replacing spaces with underscores:

```
PARENS = {'(', ')'}

def demicrosoft(string):
    return ''.join('_' if c == ' ' else c for c in string if c not in PARENS)

print(demicrosoft('Quercus stellata (26).jpg'))  # Quercus_stellata_26.jpg
```

Comment: this is the best version imho

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def demicrosoft (fn):
  return '_'.join((''.join(re.split(r'[()]', fn)).split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

From Zen of Python: Readability counts!

```
def demicrosoft (fn):
    dest = ""
    for char in fn:
        if char == ' ':
            dest += '_'
        elif char not in '()':
            dest += char
    return dest
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newString = re.sub("([\s\(\)])",lambda m:"_" if b.group(0) not in "()" else "",targetString)
```

im guessing its for a performance reasons and they want `O(N)`  the generator expression should work ... here is an `re` solution